# How to auto complete a text box using jQuery depending the value of another text box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-autocomplete

I am using 2 text boxes which is to be completed using auto-complete mechanism. It is a **codeigniter** project. The value to be filled is picked from the database using Model. In 1st text box it is working correctly with the following code.

```
$(function() {
    $("#textbox1").autocomplete({
    source:'<?php echo site_url('controller_name/function_name/arg1/arg2'); ?>'
    });
});
```

In the Second text box, the value to be filled is depending on the textbox1 value. So how to use the textbox1 value inside site_url() function.

```
$(function() {
    var data=$("#textbox1").val();
    $("#textbox2").autocomplete({
        source:"<?php echo site_url('controller_name/function_name/arg1/"+data+"');  ?>"

    });
});
```

I've tried the above method. But, the variable data is not getting any value.

Comment: are you filling textbox1 data on the load of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the controller function little bit. Instead of sending the `texbox1` value as argument2, post it using AJAX. And receive it inside the function using `$_POST['data']`.

```
$(function() {
               $( "#textbox2" ).autocomplete({
                   source: function(request, response) {
                       $.ajax({ url:"<?php echo site_url('controller_name/function_name/arg1');?>",
                       data:{'request':$("#textbox1").val()},
                       dataType: "json",
                       type: "POST",
               success: function(data){
                           response(data);
                       }
                   });
               },
               });
           });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... It is a wise one

Comment: Isn't that just a copy of the answer by @Arjun Pokkat. Wrong person got the credit?

Answer (score 2):

Change the controller function little bit. Instead of sending the `texbox1` value as arg2, post it using AJAX. And receive it inside the function using `$_POST['data']`. Send arg1 as such and post the arg2 value.

```
$(function() {
               $( "#textbox2" ).autocomplete({
                   source: function(request, response) {
                       $.ajax({ url:"<?php echo site_url('controller_name/function_name/arg1');?>",
                       data:{'request':$("#textbox1").val()},
                       dataType: "json",
                       type: "POST",
               success: function(data){
                           response(data);
                       }
                   });
               },
               });
           });
```